# Why is chroot system call not available to non root user?

Tags: chroot, setuid

I was reading description about setuid on wikipedia
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

I was unable to understand how chroot is related to setuid as mention in following paragraph from wikipedia

> The presence of setuid executables explains why the chroot system call
>   is not available to non-root users on Unix. See limitations of chroot
>   for more details.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a non-privileged user could execute a setuid program in a `chroot` jail, they could carefully construct that jail to trick the program into escalating privileges. For example, I can construct a `chroot` jail in which I'm permitted to use `sudo`, because I can control every configuration file inside that jail.

Comment: I still totally think that the expression on the wikipedia page could be rewritten to actually express this.

Comment: The [limitations section of the article on chroot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot#Limitations) goes into more detail, as the excerpt says.

Comment: @FlorinAsavoaie: The nice thing on wikipedia is that if you think "it could be written this and that", you are entitled to do so :)